# How can I ensure that .less files are cached by the browser?

Tags: css, asp.net, caching, http-headers, less

I'm working on an ASP.NET web application and am trying to ensure that files are being cached properly. I have added the following to the Web.config file:

```
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".less" mimeType="text/css" />
  <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public"
  cacheControlMaxAge="1.00:00:00" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" />
</staticContent>
```

This seems to allow most files to be cached, and I added the mime type for .less because it is only the .less file that I'm having a problem with, and I assumed that adding it to the mime types would mean it is classed as static content.

I ran Chrome's audit tool and it says "The following resources specify a "Vary" header that disables caching in most versions of Internet Explorer:" which only refers to the .less file. The network tab shows that the .less file has a "Vary: *" header.

The caching seems to be working properly because the .less file and other files are coming back with a status of 304 - correct me if I'm wrong about that, but at least it is not downloading the whole file.

Is the "Vary: *" header anything to worry about here, and is there a way that I can ensure that .less files are treated the same as any other static content files including .css? (i.e. make sure that it has the same headers and is cached in the same way)

Comment: Are you trying to take advantage of native browser support for LESS? I don't think that exists, and if it does, it's not widely supported. Instead you just provide the CSS files (generated from the LESS files) and cache those.

Comment: mason less can work client side with less.js

Comment: But using less.js for production environment is not recommended http://lesscss.org/#client-side-usage

Comment: While I agree with Alvaro I will assume Phil has a reason for doing it client side. This is what the standards say http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.44

Comment: I assumed that there was a standard way to get .less files to be cached in the same way as .css files are, but if that's not the case and they can be converted to .css, maybe that's the better option.

Comment: Would it be an option to use a cache manifest file and the application cache?